# seeing the script written inside html when i hover on tooltip

Tags: css, angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

Iam getting a problem while i place mouse on tooltip only when the page loads intially. When i login to website, after the page is loaded when i place my mouse on '?' glyphicon symbol, iam able to see the whole title script that written inside the html.

This is the below text iam seeing when i hover. This is the title with close button 'x' inside the tool tip.

```
About your score<button type=button class=close data-dismiss=popover aria-hidden=true onclick=$('#abcPopover').popover('hide')>&times;</button>
```

I made the tooltip clickable. when i click on '?' glyphicon symbol the popover is not coming on first click and the script is now hiding. when i click on '?' glyphicon symbol second time it works fine the popover is coming. This is the problem iam seeing only on when page loads and when i click on '?' glyphicon symbol the title will hide and on second click works fine and popover will come up.

This is the code i have written in html.

```
<a href="#" id="abcPopover" data-html="true"
                   title="About your score<button type=button class=close data-dismiss=popover aria-hidden=true onclick=$('#abcPopover').popover('hide')>&times;</button>"  
                   data-toggle="popover" data-content="{{abcTooltip}}" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

nesting a button in Html  tag it isn't valid HTML5 according to the [HTML5 Spec Document from W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element):

> **Content model:** Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.
>
> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables,
>   and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive
>   content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

In other words, you can nest any elements inside an  except the following:

```
<a>
```

`<audio>` (if the controls attribute is present)

```
<button>

<details>

<embed>

<iframe>
```

`<img>` (if the usemap attribute is present)

`<input>` (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state)

```
<keygen>

<label>
```

`<menu>` (if the type attribute is in the toolbar state)

`<object>` (if the usemap attribute is present)

```
<select>

<textarea>
```

`<video>` (if the controls attribute is present)

However, if your `<button>` tag is styled using CSS and doesn't look like the system's widget... Do yourself a favor, create a new class for your `<a>` tag and style it the same way.

Check this link out to create your tooltip.  [Link](http://www.htmlatoms.com/basic/how-to-create-a-tooltip-for-a-hyperlink-3/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jLkcs/5/)